# CrossShare in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using CrossShare in my Xamarin Form application.
After I did an Update of Xamarin and CrossShare I get an error: Can't convert String to ShareMessage.

```
public ICommand ShareClicked
    {
        get
        {

            return new Command(async (obj) =>
            {
                var finalText = $"{referralFriends} {Settings.ReferralId}";
                await CrossShare.Current.Share(finalText, "Share Referral Id");
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [docs](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin#api-usage)?

The method signature for Share()

```
Task<bool> Share(ShareMessage message, ShareOptions options = null);
```

so your argument needs to be a ShareMessage, not a string

```
var msg = new ShareMessage { Text = finalText };
await CrossShare.Current.Share(msg);
```

Comment: I'm new to Xamarin and C#, i did read the docs, but they made no sense to me. I been programming for over 30 years starting at C, C++ then moved to Delphi, Flex and Java. Thanks for your help.